# Adding phone number and email to addressbook gives crash in iPhoneApp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

```
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)phoneNum, nil);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, (__bridge CFTypeRef)eMailId, nil);
```

**Commenting** these two lines gives proper output (Saving the entry to AdressBook, without email and phone entry).
But, while in execution it fails and crashes the program.

Value for the Vars are:

**phoneNum** : 000-000-0000

**eMailId** : AbcdefghIjklm@qwertyuiopasdfghjk.com

Error type:    EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Any Idea?
Or need any more info??

Comment: can you please provide the detail information.What do you want to do actually..?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would be good to see where and of what type you define the vars. You may have also released the address book before those lines. (e.g. `CFRelease(multiPhone);`)
And as far as I know, `phoneNum` and `emailID` should be `ABMutableMultiValueRef`. At least that was how I did it:

Adding a **single** phone number

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, [self.contact telephone], kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);            
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);
```

Adding e-mail:

```
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiEmail = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiEmail, @"abc@abc.com", kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, multiEmail, &error);
    CFRelease(multiEmail);
```

More info on [Address Book tutorial](http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/iphone-programming-adding-a-contact-to-the-iphone-address-book/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to set just a single phone number and single mail id. Both of them i have taken of type NSString*, and then converted them, into CFStringRef.

Comment: Edited my answer. But what do you mean by mail id? something different than a mail address?

Comment: dead link for address book tutorial

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 

ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate(); 


ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue 

=ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);

//phoneNumber is the number to be save in Address Book


ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue ,phoneNumber,kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);

//EmailId is the emailId to be save in Address Book

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue ,EmailId,kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);

ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue,nil); 

// set the phone number property

ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, nil); 

ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, nil); 

CFRelease(person);
```

I Hope it may be helpfull ...